# Symfony2 using multiple databases with fosuserbundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to implement fosuserbundle with 2 diffrent entity managers in one symfony2 project. I'm using https://github.com/rollerworks/RollerworksMultiUserBundle to get this all done.
I've followed all the steps in the documentation but I've gotten an error and I don't know why ..

```
MappingException in MappingException.php line 37:
The class 'IntoPeople\AdminBundle\Entity\User' was not found in the chain
configured namespaces FOS\UserBundle\Model
```

So this mapping should be configured in my security.yml. I copied the following from the multiuserbundle documentation:

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                FOSUserBundle:
                    type:        xml
                    dir:         '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine-mapping'
                    prefix:      FOS\UserBundle\Model
                    is_bundle:   false


        customer:
            connection: customer
            mappings:
              FOSUserBundle:
                  type:        xml
                  dir:         '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine-mapping'
                  prefix:      FOS\UserBundle\Model
                  is_bundle:   false
```

So basically atm I'm not sure what I should change. I've tried to just set:

```
mappings:
    FosUserBundle: ~
```

But this doesn't work.

Anybody know how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Ok so I changed my config

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                IntoPeopleAdminBundle: ~


        customer:
            connection: customer
            mappings:
                IntoPeopleDatabaseBundle: ~
```

But I'm still getting error, now it looks like this:

```
The class 'IntoPeople\DatabaseBundle\Entity\User' was not found in the chain 
configured namespaces IntoPeople\AdminBundle\Entity, FOS\UserBundle\Model
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
orm:
  default_entity_manager: default
  entity_managers:
    default:
      connection: default
        mappings:
          FOSUserBundle:
            type: xml
            dir: '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine-mapping'
            prefix:  FOS\UserBundle\Model
            is_bundle:  false


      customer:
        connection: customer
        mappings:
          FOSUserBundle:
            type: xml
            dir: '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine-mapping'
            prefix: FOS\UserBundle\Model
            is_bundle: false
```

to

```
orm:
  default_entity_manager: default
  entity_managers:
    default:
      connection: default
        mappings:
          IntoPeopleAdminBundle: ~


      customer:
        connection: customer
        mappings:
          IntoPeopleAdminBundle: ~
```

You don't need to define mappings for `FOSUserBundle` as you're extending its base class. That solution should work.

Comment: The error just changed a little bit now: The class 'IntoPeople\DatabaseBundle\Entity\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces IntoPeople\AdminBundle\Entity, FOS\UserBundle\Model